# Using boost modules without the rest of boost?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-asio, boost-signals

I want to include boost signals in a small educational framework I am developing, but I don't want to add everything, as boost is quite big, what I need is thread, signals 1&2 and asio.

My question is regarding any dependencies or licensing issues I may have as a consequence of not having the full boost library?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Boost provide a tool called [BCP](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/tools/bcp/doc/html/index.html) that will extracts parts of Boost by itself for exactly this purpose

Answer (score 2):

Quoting [Boost license](http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt):

> Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person or
>   organization obtaining a copy of the software and accompanying
>   documentation covered by this license (the "Software") to use,
>   reproduce, display, distribute, execute, and transmit the Software,
>   and to **prepare derivative works** of the Software, and to permit
>   third-parties to whom the Software is furnished to do so, all subject
>   to the following:

Overall Boost size doesn't affect generated binaries, therefore, I think, you are concerned about your framework distribution size.

You can include all header libraries and binary Boost.System, Boost.Thread, and Boost.Asio and it should work.